# Scala SBT - sbt-native-packager, how to specify custom stage directory

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

How can I specify custom staging directory for multi-project configuration? I'm using `sbt-native-packager`

Below is the sketch of my multi module configuration. When I stage this project (`sbt stage`) the files are written to

```
common/target/universal/stage
app1/target/universal/stage
app2/target/universal/stage
```

I wan to pass an env variable `stageSuffix` like this: `sbt stage -DstageSuffix=XYZ`. This variable should make it stage the project to the following directories:

```
common/target/universal/stage-XYZ
app1/target/universal/stage-XYZ
app2/target/universal/stage-XYZ
```

I've tried modifying `stagingDirectory` in `commonSettings`, but it doesn't quite work, I'm getting errors like "References to undefined settings".

How can I make this work?

```
val stageSuffix = sys.props.getOrElse("stageSuffix", ".")

val commonSettings = Seq(
  stagingDirectory := stagingDirectory.value / stageSuffix, // this makes it fail
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...))

val common = project.in(file("common"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)

val app1 = project.in(file("app1"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(mainClass in Compile := Some("app1.Main"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...))

val app2 = project.in(file("app2"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(mainClass in Compile := Some("app2.Main"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...))

val main = project.in(file("."))
  .dependsOn(common, app1, app2)
  .aggregate(common, app1, app2)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

Comment: Was the "References to undefined settings" settings error making reference to `stagingDirectory`? Knowing which settings specifically had problems will help.

Comment: Yes, removing that setting would let the build pass, but in standard staging location: `target/universal/stage`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working like this:

```
val stagingDirectoryOverrideOpt = sys.props.get("stageSuffix").map { stageSuffix =>
  stagingDirectory in Universal := {
    val stageFile = (stagingDirectory in Universal).value
    new File(stageFile.getParentFile, s"stage-$stageSuffix")
  }
}

val app1 = project.in(file("app1"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(mainClass in Compile := Some("app1.Main"))
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(stagingDirectoryOverrideOpt.toSeq: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...))
```

Hope there is a way to make it prettier