# Scala - SBT - sbt-native-packager - Keep contents of the `stage` directory

Tags: scala, build, sbt-native-packager

This is a follow up to the question I asked (ans answered) earlier: [Scala SBT - sbt-native-packager, how to specify custom stage directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768156/scala-sbt-sbt-native-packager-how-to-specify-custom-stage-directory?noredirect=1#comment63097784_37768156)

When I alter `stagingDirectory in Universal` property (e.g. `stage-v1`) and stage the project - it works as expected. I can see my project in `target/universal/stage-v1`.

Then I specify different staging directory (`stage-v2`) and stage it. What happens first is that it deletes contents of `stage-v1` folder, and then stages it in `stage-v2`.

How can I preserve different stage builds in different staging directories?

To put this into perspective I have a build time dependency. It's a backend for a computation library which can be CPU or GPU. I have different use cases for them so I want to keep 2 builds handy at all times.

Thanks,

Anton

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to build the same application, but with different configurations is to use sbt submodules. This would look something like this:

```
lazy val application = project
lazy val cpuApplication = project.settings(...).dependsOn(application)
lazy val gpuApplication = project.settings(...).dependsOn(application)
```

The advantage of this is, that you can configure every thing very easily. You can also call everything very explicit, e.g. `gpuApplication:stage` stages the gpu application. The downside is that your `build.sbt` grows.